# How to prevent a person from doing something over a certain percent?

Tags: python, bots, discord

I know that the header of the question wasn' very clear, but I didn't quite know how to phrase it. So, what my problem is, is that I am part of a developer team for a discord bot that stimulates a stock market. What this function does is that it allows a person to buy a stock in someone else. How would I make it so that a person can't buy over a certain percent of somebody, let's say about 10%?

EDIT:
added more relevant code

```
def create_buy_embed(percent, user_mention):
    if percent >= 1:
        displayed_percent = 100
    else:
        displayed_percent = round(percent * 100, 3)
    return discord.Embed(
        description=f"You've bought {displayed_percent}% of {user_mention}"
    )
```

```
@betterbot.command(name='buy', aliases=('invest', 'b'))
async def _buy(
    ctx,
    user: Member = None,
    amount='all'
):
    percent = await investing.buy(ctx.author.id, user, amount)

    embed = create_buy_embed(percent, user.mention)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Predict what the stock will be after the transaction. If that should not be allowed, display an error message and abort the transaction. Otherwise, continue with the transaction and apply the results. Also, I don't see how anything in this function retains how much stock each user has. The information is lost as soon as the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

Going just off of the information you provided, I'll assume percent is a value that's generally 0.0-1.0 . Assuming that's the case, here's one approach:

```
def create_buy_embed(percent, user_mention):
    if percent >= 0.1:
        return discord.Embed(
            description=f"You can't buy that much!"
        )
    else:
        displayed_percent = round(percent * 100, 3)
    return discord.Embed(
        description=f"You've bought {displayed_percent}% of {user_mention}"
    )
```

Note that any handling of the math behind this output wouldn't take place here, since this just seems to give some output to the user.

Comment: It changes the message, but doesn't prevent them from doing it. I've added more relevant code that I found that might help

Comment: That's what I meant with the math not taking place here. What you'll need to do is find out exactly where the purchase happens - maybe it's a function call, maybe it's a value reassignment - and then think of the best way to stop it from happening when the % value is too great. Here's a hint based on the update you posted: Is there a way for you to compare the amount that the user _wants_ to buy with the total amount that is available?